# what's wrong in this function? (beginner cs50)

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, cs50

i'm trying to cipher a given text (string a) with a given set of letters (string b) using this function.
it compiles and runs and actually replaces the letters just not the right way.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

string replace(string a , string b);
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string code;
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        code = argv[1];
        if(strlen(argv[1]) != 26)
        {
            printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            if (isalpha(code[i]) == 0)
            {
                printf("Key must only contain alphabetic characters.\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        {
            for(int n = j + 1; n < 26; n++)
            {
                if(code[j] == code[n])
                {
                    printf("Key must not contain repeated characters.\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    string txt = get_string("plaintext:");
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n" , replace(txt , code));
    return 1;
}

string replace(string a , string b)
{
    string final = a;
    string alpha = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
    {
        for(int n = 0; n < 26; n++)
        {
            if(a[i] == alpha[n])
            {
                final[i] = b[n];
            }
        }
    }
    return final;
}
```

i just want to understand whats up with it here are some of my samples:

```
./substitution ytnshkvefxrbauqzclwdmipgjo
plaintext: hello
ciphertext hhbbq
```

and when i try it one more time that output is `ehbbq` which is the right one but every time i try it it's different.

Comment: The line `string final = a` does not make a copy of the string, so your code is modifying `a`. If you look closely at your `key`, you'll see that it translates `h` to `e` and `e` to `h`. So the first character in the plaintext (`h`) gets correctly converted to an `e`. But the second character (`e`) gets converted to an `h`, and then that `h` gets converted back to an `e`. You can patch the program by putting a `break` after `final[i] = b[n]`.